# Is there a Google Sheets add-on/extension that can achieve the “unwinding” of rows in a table that contains columns with multi-valued data:

Tags: google-apps, spreadsheet, google-drive, google

Is there a Google Sheets add-on/extension that can help me to achieve the following “unwinding” of rows in a table that contains columns with multi-valued data:

| Column A | Column B, multivalued |
| --- | --- |
| First | A,B |
| Second | C,D |

It transforms the above to:

| Column A | Column B, multivalued |
| --- | --- |
| First | A |
| First | B |
| Second | C |
| Second | D |

I can't seem to find any so far, or maybe I am not sure what is the right keyword ;(

Comment: Do you need it to replace the original data? If not (and this is the way spreadsheets are usually manipulated) then you can probably easily do this with a formula.